# Error when mapping an EventLoopFuture<Type> to an expected Type

Tags: swift, vapor, swift-nio

I've tried mapping, flat mapping, creating an `EventLoopFuture` of `Post`, etc... I'm trying to return two `db.queries` that create separate arrays of content to be rendered on the `req.view.render`, which returns an `EventLoopFuture<View>`.

My error is: `Cannot convert value of type 'EventLoopFuture<[Posts]>' to expected argument type '[Posts]'.`

Here is my code that gets called by the router:

```
func blogView(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<View> {
    struct PageContext: Encodable {
        var posts: [Posts]
        var categories: [Categories]
        var title: String
    }
    struct Posts: Encodable {
        var posts: BlogPostModel.ViewContext
        var category: BlogCategoryModel.ViewContext
    }
    struct Categories: Encodable {
        var categoryList: BlogCategoryModel.ViewContext
    }

    let posts = BlogPostModel.query(on: req.db)
        .sort(\.$date, .descending)
        .with(\.$category)
        .all()
        .mapEach {Posts(posts: $0.viewContext, category: $0.category.viewContext)}
    let categories = BlogCategoryModel.query(on: req.db)
        .sort(\.$title)
        .all()
        .mapEach {Categories(categoryList: $0.viewContext)}
    let returnContext = PageContext(posts: posts,categories: categories, title: categories)
    return req.view.render("Blog/Frontend/Blog", returnContext)
}
```

EDIT: re my comment below. This snippet returns the Posts (and associated Categories).  Trying to add a second `db.query` to the return.

```
func blogView(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<View> {
    struct Context: Encodable {
        struct PostWithCategory: Encodable {
            var category: BlogCategoryModel.ViewContext
            var post: BlogPostModel.ViewContext }
        let title: String
        let items: [PostWithCategory]
    }

    return BlogPostModel.query(on: req.db)
        .sort(\.$date, .descending)
        .with(\.$category)
        .all()
        .mapEach {
            Context.PostWithCategory(category: $0.category.viewContext, post: $0.viewContext) 
        }
        .flatMap {
            let context = Context(title: "Blog Posts", items: $0)
            return req.view.render("Blog/Frontend/Blog", context)
        }
}
```

Comment: Seems clear enough. `posts` is a Future, so you can't assign it as a PageContext's `posts`. I don't know vapor but it looks to me like you have a chain of operators from your Future and you need to get the _output_ of that Future — it needs to actually _run_. You need to _respond_ to the Future running, for example in a `whenComplete` operator.

Comment: yes I get that... I 'm struggling with the vapor syntax.  I'm trying to flatten the posts.  I would use a .flatMap() in the chain after the .mapeach to flatten the future post to get the post however, it then throws an error on the .mapEach, complaining about NewValue not being inferred.

Comment: I don't think it's the syntax that's giving you problems. I think you are not grasping what a Future and its accompanying pipeline _is_. It's a chain of operations that will happen at some time in the unknown future. At the end of that chain — not outside the chain, but _in_ it, as its final operator — you can receive the value that pops out the end of the pipeline. That is where you would attach the `whenComplete` operator, and it is in the `whenComplete` operator that you would then create your Posts object.

Comment: But please note that the last line of your code reveals an even greater misconception. You cannot _return_ the value that is generated by this pipeline, for the simple reason that the pipeline will run _in the future_. That's what a Future is! The method will return _before_ the Future has a chance to run and generate its output. So your entire approach here, if I'm not mistaken, is barking up a very wrong tree. (I'm just guessing based on my knowledge of what "asynchronous" means and what a Future is in other frameworks such as Combine.)

Comment: yes... I get that... Here is code that works... I'm just trying to add a second db.query to the chain before it gets returned...  This snippet gets my Posts (and associated categories) and returns the values to the Future<View> assigned to the req.  What I'm trying to do is also return the array of Categories (not just those assigned to posts).     Pls see the snippet I added in my edit just now...

Comment: I appreciate your help Matt...  I'm working with chaining an ".and", which may get me the two futures together before I flatmap them both so I can return the future view. again... I appreciate you weighing in... 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that your `PageContext` type has properties of types `[Post]` and `[Categories]`, but you are trying to initialize a `PageContext` using `EventLoopFuture<[Post]>` and `EventLoopFuture<[Categories]>`. What you can do is use NIO's `.and` method to combine 2 `EventLoopFuture` objects into 1:

```
posts.and(categories) // EventLoopFuture<([Post], [Categories])>
```

You can then map on this new `EventLoopFuture` to get the tuple and create your `PageContext` instance:

```
return posts.and(categories).flatMap { posts, categories in
    let returnContext = PageContext(posts: posts, categories: categories, title: "Blog Posts")
    return req.view.render("Blog/Frontend/Blog", context)
}
```

Comment: Yes! thanks Caleb.  I knew I needed to combine the two futures... just wasn't sure how to .flatten both at once.  Really appreciate you laying out the full closure too!! @Caleb++. 